# Compare MongoDB ISODate with string

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

I'm currently working on a backend build with MERN and Typescript.

The problem comes when i try to compare Dates, which are are saved in Mongo as Date(ISODate(for example: "2022-09-14T16:00:00.000+00:00") and get compared to a string (for example: "2022-14-09").

I tried to convert the string with the Help of new Date(string) and compare then, but unfortunately it didn't work.
I tried several Methods but they all don't work.

Do you have an idea?

```
data = await collections.events
          ?.find({
            location: params["place"],
            persons: { $gte: parseInt(params["persons"], 10) },
            time: { $gte: new Date(params["date"]) },
          })
          .toArray();
```

Comment: I think it should work. Maybe try additional brackets. `(new Date(params["date"]))`. Or use a date library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) (still useful, despite deprecated), [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a Date to ISOString(), which corresponds to your MongoDB Date. Try not to use momentJs (deprecated), you can also just add 'T00:00:00.000Z' at the end of `params["date"]` (not the best practice)

```
new Date(params["date"]).toISOString()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Btw I recommend you to do more verifications with your variables, like if you parseInt NaN, it will return undefined and your request can give you wrong results ;)

Comment: Big thank you it worked! And I will have a look at the verifications again ;)